# (Windows Form C#)Нужно получить данные курса BTC к рублю и вывести в textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу маленький проектик,задача проста:при открытии приложения получить текущий курс BTC и вывести его в текстбоксе,каким образом и с какого сайта лучше будет реализовать получение данных

Comment: Каким удобно и с какого вам лучше. Критериев выбора полно, от стабильности сайта в вашем регионе, до точности данных. Решать вам.

Comment: А можно по конкретнее про существующие способы?

Comment: Открываете любой поисковик, пишете "Курс биткоина", находите удобный для вас сайт, используете.

Comment: Возможно я не конкретизировал первую часть вопроса ,мне нужна помощь с получением данных ,то есть я не знаю способов как можно взять данные курса валюты для последующего  использования

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала Вам нужно найти поставщика курса биткоина и извлечь значение курса

Для примера возьмём сайт https://myfin.by/crypto-rates/bitcoin-rub

Загружаем страницу как строку например через WebClient:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string page = client.DownloadString("https://myfin.by/crypto-rates/bitcoin-rub");
```

В коде страницы ищем текущий курс:

```
Искать будем эту строку:
<div class="birzha_info_head_rates"> 3590770RUB <div> </div>

const string key = "<div class=\"birzha_info_head_rates\">";
int index = page.IndexOf(key);
string rateStr = page.Substring(index + key.Length);
index = rateStr.IndexOf("</div>");
rateStr = rateStr.Substring(0, index).Trim();
```

Выводим курс в текстбокс:

```
textBox1.Text = rateStr;
```

Проверил код - результат есть:
[image: Результат работы программы]

Comment: лучше мспользовать `HttpClient` и для разбора html `AngleSharp`, к примеру

Comment: KuzCode, для автора с учётом заданного вопроса возможно будет трудно работать с асинхронными методами HttpClient, поэтому указал на WebClient

Comment: Не нужно использовать в ответах заведомо устаревшие классы. От асинхронного программирования еще никто не умирал. То что вы используете в коде, в .NET 7 будет вообще с корнями выпилено из дотнета, а в .NET 6 уже помечено как `[Obsolete]`. То есть этот код скоро превратится в тыкву. Смысл?

Comment: `using var client = new HttpClient(); string text = await client.GetStringAsync("...")` если боитесь что автор испугается `await`, добавьте эту ссылку в ответ https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: А еще круче было бы, ели бы вы использовали нормальный html парсер типа HtmlAgilityPack или AngleSharp, а не вот это вот всё :) А еще лучше найти json API.